# PHP how set default value to a variable in the class?

Tags: php, class, variables

```
class A{
    public $name;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->name = 'first';
    }

    public function test1(){
        if(!empty($_POST["name"]))
        {
            $name = 'second';
        }
        echo $name;
    }

$f = new A;
$f->test1();
```

Why don't we get `first` and how set right default value variable `$name` only for class A?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: `$this->name` and `$name` are two different variables...

Comment: @deceze i know it, but how set in class default value for variable that print `$name` is `first`? if make `public $name; $this->name='first';` it not will be print `first`.

Comment: I'm saying you need to use `$this->name` instead of `$name` inside your `test1()` function. The other part was fine as it was, you can revert that to your initial version.

Comment: @deceze it ok, i understood you and i understood how this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a constructor to set the initial values (or pretty much do anything for that matter) as you need to like this:

```
class example
{

    public $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name="first";
    }

}
```

Then you can use these default values in your other functions.

```
class example
{

    public $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name="first";
    }

    public function test1($inputName)
    {
        if(!empty($inputName))
        {
            $this->name=$inputName;
        }
        echo "The name is ".$this->name."\r\n";
    }

}

$ex=new example();
$ex->test1(" "); // prints first.
$ex->test1("Bobby"); // prints Bobby
$ex->test1($_POST["name"]); // works as you expected it to.
```

Answer (score 6):

you have two options to set the default values for the class attributes:

Option 1: set at the parameter level.

```
class A 
{
    public $name = "first";

    public function test1()
    {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

$f = new A();
$f->test1();
```

Option 2: the magic method __construct() always being executed each time that you create a new instance.

```
class A 
{
    public $name;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->name = 'first';
    }

    public function test1()
    {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

$f = new A();
$f->test1();
```

Comment: Just wanted to know, that is there any difference between the two approaches? Is there any correct way to do it, or any best practice? Which one will you advise us to use? Thank you

Answer (score -4):

Use `isset()` to assign a default to a variable that may already have a value:

```
if (! isset($cars)) {
    $cars = $default_cars;
}
```

Use the ternary `(a ? b : c)` operator to give a new variable a (possibly default) value:

```
$cars = isset($_GET['cars']) ? $_GET['cars'] : $default_cars;
```

Comment: This does not answer the original question. Please have a look at the question again. *Anyway, it would have been a good answer if the question was different.* :)